# Android: "Can't resolve method 'setVisibility' in group"

Tags: java, android, visibility

This piece of code fails to compile because the method `setVisibility()` cannot be resolved.

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        calenderButton.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
               calendarGroup.setVisibility(
                       calendarGroup.getVisibility() == View.GONE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE
               );
        });

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String task = enterTodo.getText().toString().trim();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(task)){
                    Task myTask = new Task(task, Priority.HIGH,
                    Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),
                            false);
                    TaskViewModel.insert(myTask);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the actual build output/stack trace?

Comment: What is calendarGroup ? I mean where did you create it ?
Also, you can simplify that your if statement to just : calendarGroup.setVisibility(!calendarGroup.getVisibility())